# Do I need to re-install .NET (or something) after mscorlib.dll chkdsk error?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, .net, chkdsk

After noticing that some periodic hanging behavior on my Dell XPS 210 (running Vista 32-bit) seemed correlated to disk activity, I ran `chkdsk /r`. The system seems much better, for now.

However, I still have a concern. It found and fixed a bunch of files but they were mostly just data such as pictures. Two of them were .NET DLLs, however, and I'm wondering if I'm going to see flakiness from .NET applications if I don't re-install .NET? Here are the relevant error lines. I'm not sure how to interpret them; was `chkdsk` able to successfully recreate the DLLs, or not?

```
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 225726 of name
\Windows\MICROS~1.NET\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\V40_40~1.0__\mscorlib.dll. 
Read failure with status 0xc0000185 at offset 0x275cbce000 for 0x10000 bytes. 
[blah blah blah]
Read failure with status 0xc0000185 at offset 0x275cbe9000 for 0x1000 bytes. 
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 225906 of name 
\Windows\MICROS~1.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SYSTEM~3.SER\V40_40~1.0__\SYSTEM~1.DLL. 
Read failure with status 0xc0000185 at offset 0x272686c000 for 0x10000 bytes. 
[blah blah blah]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sfc /scannow`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/system_file_checker.mspx?mfr=true) which will perform a check of your system files and replace any corrupt files, including your .net DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

That's .Net 4.0 which not many applications use (yet) so you probably haven't seen any issues.  I would uninstall .Net v4 and then re-install it just to be sure.